# finding and erasing duplicates in one vector and erasing values in another vector

Tags: c++, c++11, unique, stdvector

I have two vectors of the form `std::vector<int> a` and `std::vector<double> b`, for example

```
a= 1,2,3,3,4,5,6;
b=0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.1, -0.2;
```

both vectors are of the same size and in fact they work like a XY pair `((1,0.1) ,  (2,0.3)...etc)`. Mercifully, `a` is sorted from less to more always

I want to find the duplicates in the first vector and then erase the first of them, in my example the output should be:

```
a= 1,2,3,4,5,6;
b=0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.1, -0.2;
```

in MATLAB I would do something like this:

```
b(find(diff(a) == 0)) = []; 
a(find(diff(a) == 0)) = [];
```

I know I can do it the old fashioned way using for loops and if statements but I am sure there is a more elegant way to do it in c++ with containers and iterators. Searching the internet there is plenty of examples for erasing the duplicate in the first vector but not of using the same indexes to erase the elements in the second vector.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Instead of having parallel vectors why not have one vector that stores both pieces of data in a single element?  Then it becomes trivial to do what you want.

Comment: Or populate your data into a `std::map<key, value>` initially, and you won't need to erase duplicates anymore since map does not support duplicate keys

Comment: Are you really storing `0.3` in your `int` vector?

Comment: My bad, vector b is double not int, and they come from another function that I  cannot modify.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to get around using for loops and if statements.

```
    iterator j = b.begin();
    iterator ahead = a.begin();
    ahead++;
    while(1) {
        if(ahead* == behind*) { // If we have a duplicate
            a.erase(ahead);     // we need to erase the entry in a
            b.erase(j);         // and the entry in b
        }
        else {                  // Otherwise, just move on
            j++;
            ahead++;
            behind++;
        }
        if(ahead == a.end())    // Once we reach the end of the vectors, end the loop
            break;
    }
```

That might work. I don't exactly know how `erase()` works, but I think the logic should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you'll find few (if any) well written examples of this is that most people are like to start by defining something like this:

```
struct coord {
    int x;
    double y;

    // Since we want X values unique, that's what we compare by:    
    bool operator==(coord const &other) const {
        return x == other.x;
    }
};
```

Using that, we can get unique X and corresponding Y pairs without any explicit loops pretty easily, because the standard library already provides algorithms for that specific purpose:

```
std::vector<coord> ab;
// populate ab here ...

// ensure only unique X values, removing the corresponding Y when we remove an X
ab.erase(std::unique(ab.begin(), ab.end()), ab.end());
```

If you really need to maintain `a` and `b` as separate arrays instead, I'd probably still do something *fairly* similar, but use a [zip iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) to create something that looks/acts similar enough that you can still use `unique` and `erase` to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be an easier way that this?

```
// compare the index vector by using the
// values of another vector
struct compare_by_other
{
    std::vector<int>& v;

    compare_by_other(std::vector<int>& v): v(v) {}

    bool operator()(std::size_t idx1, std::size_t idx2) const
        { return v[idx1] == v[idx2]; }
};

std::vector<int>    a = {1  , 2  , 3  , 3  , 3  , 4  , 4  , 5  };
std::vector<double> b = {0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.9, 2.5, 9.6, 0.3, 2.4};

// create an index to track which indexes need to be removed
std::vector<std::size_t> indexes(a.size());
std::iota(std::begin(indexes), std::end(indexes), 0);

// remove all the indexes that the corresponding vector finds duplicated
auto end = std::unique(std::begin(indexes), std::end(indexes), compare_by_other(a));

// erase all those elements whose indexes do not appear in the unique
// portions of the indexes vector

a.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](auto& n){
    return std::find(std::begin(indexes), end, std::distance(a.data(), &n)) == end;
}), std::end(a));

// same for b

b.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(b), std::end(b), [&](auto& n){
    return std::find(std::begin(indexes), end, std::distance(b.data(), &n)) == end;
}), std::end(b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't an elegant way that I know of to do this in vanilla C++.

If you're willing to use a library, Eric Neibler's [Range-V3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/) (currently on its way into the standard) lets you do this in a semi-pleasant way:

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace rng = ranges::v3;

int main()
{ 
    std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    std::vector<double> b{0.1, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.1, -0.2};

    auto view = rng::view::zip(a, b);

    auto result = rng::unique(view, [](auto&& x, auto&& y) {
         return x.first == y.first;
    });

    // This is a bit of a hack...
    const auto new_end_idx = rng::distance(rng::begin(view), result);

    a.erase(a.begin() + new_end_idx, a.end());
    b.erase(b.begin() + new_end_idx, b.end());

    std::cout << rng::view::all(a) << '\n';
    std::cout << rng::view::all(b) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[0.1,0.3,0.2,0.6,0.1,-0.2]
```

[Wandbox link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3cgrwFzzbkqgtPwT)

It's still not quite ideal (because it's not possible to get the raw iterators back out of a `view::zip` iterator as far as I can tell), but it's not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion without the code all worked out:

Easy, less efficient way:

1. Use a [zip iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) to treat the two vectors as a single range of two-tuples/pairs. (It doesn't have to be Boost's, but the standard library doesn't have one AFAICR). You've now reduced the problem to filtering out dupes with a custom comparison criterion (assuming you don't mind the output is not two distinct arrays)
2. Build a set of the two-tuples, using this constructor:

   ```
   template< class InputIt >
   set( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Compare& comp = Compare(),
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
   ```

   in your case, the default allocator is fine, but you want to set the comparator to something like

   ```
    [](const std::tuple<int, double>& lhs,
       const std::tuple<int, double>& rhs) -> bool
    { 
         return std::get<0>(lhs) < std::get<0>(rhs); 
    }
   ```

   or you can write a proper function doing them same thing. And this depends on whether your zip iterator exposes tuples or std::pair's of course.

That's it!

A more efficient thing to do would be to build a vector of tuples, but populate it using a `std::copy_if` on the zipped iterator range.